# Emacs bindings documentation

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing some bindings to lambdas in my `~/.emacs` and would like to have a description of what the function does appear when I do (for example) `C-c ?`. I tried to put a string immediately after `lambda ()` but that still does nothing. How do I get something relevant to appear in the binding column?

Example that still functionally works but documentation doesn't:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") (lambda ()
                  "Moves the current line up by one"
                  (interactive)
                  (let ((col (current-column)))
                (transpose-lines 1)
                (forward-line -2)
                (forward-char col))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `defun` to define your interactive function and bind to that.

```
(defun my-func ()
  "Moves the current line up by one"
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (current-column)))
    (transpose-lines 1)
    (forward-line -2)
    (forward-char col)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'my-func)
```

Comment: Here, it's worth pointing out that you should generally bind 'defuns' rather than than lambdas, because of things like `C-h k`